# Compare values with respective fields in database

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 fields in database:

```
levelOne , levelTwo, levelThree // Table Name = levels
```

With values:

```
levelOne    = 300,
levelTwo    = , // This field is empty
levelThree = , // This field is empty
```

Now I have a variable which has to be compared with the respective fields.

```
$var = L1_200;
```

Now `L1_200` means its a level 1 value so it has to be compared with `levelOne` field in a query and vice versa. SO how can I write the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
  $var = 'L1_200';
  $sql = 'select * from table_name where 1 ';
  $arr = explode('_', $var);
  if($arr[0] == 'L1'){
      $sql .= 'AND levelOne = \''.$arr[1].'\'';
  } else if($arr[0] == 'L2'){
      $sql .= 'AND levelTwo = \''.$arr[1].'\'';
  } else if($arr[0] == 'L3'){
      $sql .= 'AND levelThree = \''.$arr[1].'\'';
  }
```

Now use $sql